# Find $x$ such that a point in contained in this plane.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find an $x$ such that the point 
$\begin{pmatrix}
8 \\
- 16 \\
7 
\end{pmatrix}$ 
is contained in the plane through the origin and parallel to  $\begin{pmatrix}
-0.5 \\
-0.5 \\
x
\end{pmatrix}$ 
and 
$\begin{pmatrix}
0.5 \\
-0.7 \\
0.4
\end{pmatrix}$.

I'm not sure how to proceed, can anyone help?

Comment: The plane will be of the form $\vec r(s,t) = s(-0.5,-0.5,x) + t(0.5,-0.7,0.4)$.  Set $\vec r(s,t)=(8,-16,7)$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: I'm going to try that now.

Answer (score 2):

Because $(8,-16,7)$ and $(0,0,0)$ are points on the plane, $\left<8-0,-16-0,7-0\right>$ is a vector on the plane. So your two vectors that define the plane are $\left<8,-16,7\right>$ and $\left<0.5,-0.7,0.4\right>$. The cross product of these vectors is $\left<-1.5,0.3,2.4\right>$, which is the normal vector of your plane. Because the plane contains the origin, the equation of the plane is
$$-1.5u+0.3v+2.4w=0$$
Setting $u=-0.5$, $v=-0.5$, and $w=x$ we have
$$0.6+2.4x=0$$
and $x=-\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

The plane through the origin parallel to your vectors is

$$ P = \left \{ s \begin{pmatrix} -0.5 \\ -0.5 \\ x \end{pmatrix} + t \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 \\ -0.7 \\ 0.4 \end{pmatrix} \,\, | \,\, s, t \in \mathbb{R} \right \}. $$

For the point to lie in $P$, there must exist $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ s \begin{pmatrix} -0.5 \\ -0.5 \\ x \end{pmatrix} + t \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 \\ -0.7 \\ 0.4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ -16 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Writing it explicitly, we have

$$ -0.5 s + 0.5 t = 8, \\ -0.5 s - 0.7 t = -16, \\ sx + 0.4 t = 7.$$

Solving the first two equations will give you $s,t$. Plugging it into the third equation, you will find $x$.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!